# Problem with getting access to MongoDB Atlas after deployment

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I just deploy I MERN stack app into Heroku, I connect it to MongoDB Atlas and everything works fine locally (login, sign in, adding, removing), but when on Heroku is not working (I used the MongoDB Atlas string), but it's not working. Can someone please help me?

server.js :

```
// SignUp
app.post("/account/users/signUp", (req, res) => {
  SignUp.signUp(req, res);
});
// Login
app.post("/account/users/login", (req, res) => {
  login.login(req, res);
});
// wishList
app.post("/account/users/favorites", (req, res) => {
  addFavorites.addFavorites(req, res);
});
//Get
app.get("/account/users/favoritesList/:id", (req, res) => {
  getFavorite.getFavorite(req, res);
});
//Get onWishList
app.get("/account/users/onWishList/:id", (req, res) => {
  onWishList.onWishList(req, res);
});
//handleDelete
app.delete("/account/users/favoritesList/:userId/:movieId", (req, res) => {
  handleDelete.handleDelete(req, res);
});


// Serve The react app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));
});

// Serve Static Assets if in Production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production" || true) {
  const root = path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')
  app.use(express.static(root));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
  })

}
// Port
// const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
// app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));

let server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, function () {
  let port = server.address().port;
  console.log("Express is working on port " + port);
});
```

maybe I did something wrong ?

Comment: Don't put  your connection string inside the code, put it inside enviroment variables.

Comment: this is supposed to solve the problem? only this? and how I do it?

Comment: no it will not solve your problem, but it is not secure to show your password publicly

Comment: i got an error like this :  URI malformed, cannot be parsed, and what to do after that

Comment: Can not help without seeing what are you trying, Paste some code that you wrote and make sure not to put your mongo URI in example.